# Scammers try to push Windows App to Ubuntu & Sock puppets on askubuntu.com

Tags: discussion, spam-handling

Had [posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353111/installing-perfectapp-on-ubuntu-12-04) (now gone) a question on how to install a franchise 
fraud application on Ubuntu, as he seemingly can't get it to work. Researching what this application is, I couldn't help myself but think that the whole thing is a scam. I posted my concerns first as a answer and later deleted it and posted it as a comment.

By then two different people showed up and "answered" the question praising their pyramid scheme website and it's wonderful app.

I both find this funny and concerning. I'm pretty new to Ask Ubuntu. Is it the right way to to flag the question as spam and kill the whole thing?

Or maybe, should some admin have a look at and maybe check from what ip the question and the answers are coming from and analyse it some more?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yeah, good catch. I completely agree with your assessment.

Bombs away. Pew Pew.

In addition to destroying all three accounts and their posts, I have requested the domain is blocked making it impossible for people in the future to post similar posts.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for bringing judicious napalm as required.

Comment: @ThomasW. I don't want to be too explicit about what is actually blocked in the open (the less help we give spammers the better IMO) but we have something in place and we'll expand that if we need to later on.

Comment: You should have used the "this post has been burninated" image. But I like your [onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) :)

Answer (score 1):

Ummm...just an idea... Did anyone realize that even thought this main post looked legit (which it may well be) not only does direct link to the website by domain name but also hyper-linked through "perfectapp" keyword? This is a common practice by blackhat marketers, and since people have commented and raised the score, it only adds gravity or influence to it. If you really want this to seem legit, remove the links to the offending website. Ubuntu carries a high PR value, so any links from this site are substantial.

Comment: You are right. You can flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to nuke the links.

Comment: Or I could change the link-text and try to [Google Bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb) it.